# Octave / Matlab: How to plot the roots of a polynomial

Tags: math, matlab, octave

Im trying to plot the roots of a polynomial, and i just cant get it.

First i create my polynomial

```
p5 = [1 0 0 0 0 -1] %x^5 - 1
r5 = roots(p5)
stem (p5)
```

Im using the `stem` function, but I would like to remove the stems, and just get the circle around the roots.

Is this possible, is stem the right command?

Thanks in advance,

PS: This is not homework, but very close, will tag it if requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have complex roots that you want to plot with the real part on the x-axis and the imaginary part on the y-axis, you can just use the [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) function:

```
plot(r5,'o');
```

If you are wanting to plot the function *and* the roots together, you will have to ignore the complex roots (as yuk mentions in the comment below):

```
p5 = [1 0 0 0 0 -1];
r5 = roots(p5);
realRoots = r5(isreal(r5));  %# Gets just the real roots
x = -2:0.01:2;               %# x values for the plot
plot(x,polyval(p5,x));       %# Evaluate the polynomial and plot it
hold on;                     %# Add to the existing plot
plot(realRoots,zeros(size(realRoots)),'o');  %# Plot circles for the roots
```

Comment: Notice that r5 contains complex numbers and plot will ignore imaginary part. To plot real root only you can do: plot(r5(imag(r5)==0),zeros(sum(imag(r5)==0)),'o');

Comment: @yuk: Good catch. I updated the answer using the ISREAL function. ;)

Comment: @yuk, gnovice: Thank you both for your help, but how would i plot all roots (both img and real ) ?

Comment: @Tom: The first part of my new answer shows how to plot both the real and imaginary parts of all the roots together.

Comment: @gnovice, thanks, ended up using plot (real(r5),imag(r5),'o')

Comment: @Tom: Then you can do just plot(r5,'o')

Comment: @yuk, thanks, i was missing the 'o' and got a continuous line.